# how to explain warning about argument passing to function

Tags: compiler-warnings

why the program gived a warning about foo's argument?

```
void foo(const char **p)
{ 

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
      foo(argv);          //problem is here
      return 0;
}
```

MinGW gives a waring like this:

```
warning : passing argument 1 of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Answer (score 0):

Function foo() is expecting const char ** but argv is char **.

Your code can be written in one of 3 ways.

Change the definition of foo() to expect char ** instead of const char **.

```
void foo(char **p)
```

or

Change argv in main() to const char **.

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
```

or

Cast argv as (const char **) when passed to foo().

```
foo((const char **)argv);
```

Comment: this is a question I found in a website and it says:sending a normal pointer to a function requiring const pointer does not give any warning,so I thought there exits a prolbem which I don't know~